# Metal shader stage_in

Tags: swift, shader, metal, clip

I have a simple Metal shader downloaded from here: [https://medium.com/@MalikAlayli/metal-with-scenekit-create-your-first-shader-2c4e4e983300](http://%20https://medium.com/@MalikAlayli/metal-with-scenekit-create-your-first-shader-2c4e4e983300). I have modified it by adding `clip_distance` to `VertexOut`. Everything works fine if `clip_distance` is a float. Since I need 6 clipping planes, I try to define it as a vector `[[clip_distance]][6]`. However, Xcode complains about the `textureSamplerFragment` routine, saying "Type 'VertexOut' is not valid for attribute 'stage_in'". I am new to Metal shader and have no idea about how to fix the error.

Can anyone give me a direction? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct NodeBuffer {
    float4x4 modelTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewTransform;
    float4x4 normalTransform;
    float2x3 boundingBox;
};

struct VertexInput {
    float3 position  [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
    float2 uv [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0)]];
};


struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float clip_distance [[clip_distance]][6];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex VertexOut textureSamplerVertex(VertexInput in [[ stage_in ]], constant NodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]]) {
    VertexOut out;
    out.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
    out.clip_distance[0] = 1.5 - in.position.x;
    out.uv = in.uv;
    return out;
}

fragment float4 textureSamplerFragment(VertexOut out [[ stage_in ]], texture2d<float, access::sample> customTexture [[texture(0)]]) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler(coord::normalized, filter::linear, address::repeat);
    return customTexture.sample(textureSampler, out.uv );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf):

**clip_distance** attribute data types should be either **float** or **float[n]**, **n** - must be known at compile time. You should change your shader logic to the corresponding requirements.

Comment: This is what I’ve guessed. But it still seems strange to me that there is no easier way to add multiple clip planes